# Edit a field with expression QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to give a value of 0 when the field is null?
You will tell me to give a default value I did it. 
I'm working on a data collection project using qfield. I gave a default value to my field so that it would be always filled, yet operators delete this value and forget to give another.
So I want to populate the value of 0 when it's null.
If you have any idea tell me please.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Enter this into the field calculator.

```
CASE WHEN "fieldname" = NULL
THEN "fieldname" = '0'
ELSE "fieldname" = "fieldname"
END
```

Comment: I did this before but when I create a new feature let the field null nothing changes.

Comment: You either punch in a value manually, even if it's 0, or you run this afterwards. Standard values are something I didn't come across in QGis yet.

Comment: I created a trigger in database so when the new value entered is null it will turn to 0. Thaks for you help.